# How to improve INSERT performance (rows per second) to CockroachDB (about 20 times slower compared to PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database-performance, bulkinsert, sqlperformance, cockroachdb

The Python3 script attached to the end of this post creates a simple table with 5 `INT` columns, 3 of them with an index.

Then it uses [multi-row inserts](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/insert.html#insert-multiple-rows-into-an-existing-table) to fill the table.

At the beginning it manages to insert about 10000 rows per second.

```
Took   0.983 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  10171 rows per second.
Took   0.879 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  11376 rows per second.
Took   0.911 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  10982 rows per second.
Took   1.180 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   8477 rows per second.
Took   1.030 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   9708 rows per second.
Took   1.114 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   8975 rows per second.
```

But when the table already contains about 1000000 rows, the performance goes down to about 2000 rows per second.

```
Took   3.648 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   2741 rows per second.
Took   3.026 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   3305 rows per second.
Took   5.495 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   1820 rows per second.
Took   6.212 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   1610 rows per second.
Took   5.952 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   1680 rows per second.
Took   4.872 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =   2053 rows per second.
```

For comparison: When using PostgreSQL instead of CockroachDB the performance is about 40000 rows per second the whole time.

```
Took   0.212 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  47198 rows per second.
Took   0.268 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  37335 rows per second.
Took   0.224 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  44548 rows per second.
Took   0.307 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  32620 rows per second.
Took   0.234 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  42645 rows per second.
Took   0.262 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  38124 rows per second.

Took   0.301 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  33254 rows per second.
Took   0.220 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  45547 rows per second.
Took   0.260 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  38399 rows per second.
Took   0.222 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  45136 rows per second.
Took   0.213 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  46950 rows per second.
Took   0.211 s to INSERT 10000 rows, i.e. performance =  47436 rows per second.
```

Is there a way to improve the performance when using CockroachDB?

Since the table is filled continuously, first filling the table and only later adding the indexes is not an option.

---

`db_insert_performance_test.py`:

```
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import psycopg2


def init_table(cur):
    """Create table and DB indexes"""
    cur.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE entities (a INT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL,
                               c INT NOT NULL, d INT NOT NULL,
                               e INT NOT NULL);""")
    cur.execute('CREATE INDEX a_idx ON entities (a);')
    cur.execute('CREATE INDEX b_idx ON entities (b);')
    cur.execute('CREATE INDEX c_idx ON entities (c);')
    # d and e does not need an index.


def create_random_event_value():
    """Returns a SQL-compatible string containing a value tuple"""
    def randval():
        return random.randint(0, 100000000)
    return f"({randval()}, {randval()}, {randval()}, {randval()}, {randval()})"


def generate_statement(statement_template, rows_per_statement):
        """Multi-row insert statement for 200 random entities like this:
        INSERT INTO entities (a, b, ...) VALUES (1, 2, ...), (6, 7, ...), ...
        """
        return statement_template.format(', '.join(
                create_random_event_value()
                for i in range(rows_per_statement)))


def main():
    """Write dummy entities into db and output performance."""

    # Config
    database = 'db'
    user = 'me'
    password = 'pwd'
    host, port = 'cockroach-db', 26257
    #host, port = 'postgres-db', 5432

    rows_per_statement = 200
    statements_per_round = 50
    rounds = 100
    statement_template = 'INSERT INTO entities (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES {}'

    # Connect to DB
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database, user=user, password=password,
                            host=host, port=port)
    conn.set_session(autocommit=True)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    init_table(cur)

    for _ in range(rounds):
        # statements_per_round multi-row INSERTs
        # with rows_per_statement rows each
        batch_statements = [generate_statement(statement_template,
                                               rows_per_statement)
                            for _ in range(statements_per_round)]

        # Measure insert duration
        start = timer()
        for batch_statement in batch_statements:
            cur.execute(batch_statement)
        duration = timer() - start

        # Calculate performance
        row_count = rows_per_statement * statements_per_round
        rows_per_second = int(round(row_count / duration))
        print('Took {:7.3f} s to INSERT {} rows, '
            'i.e. performance = {:>6} rows per second.'
            ''.format(duration, row_count, rows_per_second), flush=True)

    # Close the database connection.
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To quickly reproduce my results here is a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  cockroach-db:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v2.0.3
    command: start --insecure --host cockroach-db --vmodule=executor=2
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z cockroach-db 26258

  cockroach-db-init:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v2.0.3
    depends_on:
     - cockroach-db
    entrypoint: /cockroach/cockroach sql --host=cockroach-db --insecure -e "CREATE DATABASE db; CREATE USER me; GRANT ALL ON DATABASE db TO me;"

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:10.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: me
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z postgres-db 5432

  db-insert-performance-test:
    image: python:3.6
    depends_on:
     - cockroach-db-init
     - postgres-db
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    working_dir: /
    entrypoint: bash -c "pip3 install psycopg2 && python3 code/db_insert_performance_test.py"
```

To start testing just run `docker-compose up db-insert-performance-test`.

Comment: Do you need indexes at start? Or you can create them after fill the table with data? It can speed up things. Also interesting that PostgreSQL have only **40k** inserts to so trivial table with 5 integers. Do you prepare statement before inserts and reuse it? I have tested performance for Firebird3 database using ArrayDML and with so trivial table i got **360k** inserts per second.

Comment: @Livius The table is filled continuously, so first filling it and only later adding the indexes unfortunately is not an option (edited my question accordingly). From my understanding prepared statements only help in case of statements that are complicated to parse but quick to execute. Nevertheless I just tested with a single-row-insert-prepared statement (`PREPARE insertentityplan as INSERT INTO entities (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`) and this is about 10 times slower compared to the multi-row-insert-non-prepared statement.

Comment: I see that you use autocommit and this can be costly here. What happen when you change processing into single transaction commited after whole process? https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-c++-app-with-cockroachdb.html#transaction-with-retry-logic

Comment: @Livius Just tested it out with `conn.set_session(autocommit=False)` and `conn.commit()` after each large chunk (containing multiple multi-row-insert statements), but it did not result in any measurable difference.

Comment: Then it looks like some configuration problem like some cahing or file expansion settings

Comment: @Livius Any recommendation what I should start to read/investigate to find such a problem?

Answer (score 5):

CockroachDB stores data inside "ranges", and ranges split when they get to 64MB. Initially, the table fits into one range so each insert is a single-range operation. After the range splits, each insert needs to involve multiple ranges to update the table and indexes; so there is an expected drop-off in performance there.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean CockroachDB probably is not the right tool for the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: I wouldn't jump to that conclusion! What is the problem that you're trying to solve? You haven't said. Are there specific performance targets you need to hit? Remember that Cockroach is a distributed database, so you'll be able to scale performance roughly linearly with the number of nodes in your cluster as long as your workload is evenly distributed—as it is in the example workload you've provided.

Comment: More concretely, you may see better performance with a different INSERT batch size. The optimal batch size is highly workload dependent. If you're only trying to load initial data into the table, you could also consider using IMPORT (https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/import.html), which is much faster.

Comment: @benesch Thanks. I already tried out different batch sizes, and the one I'm using in this example is quite optimal in this test. Using `IMPORT` is no option, since it is not just an initial filling of the table, but will run all the time. My performance target is roughly a minimum of 2000 rows per second, but having some wiggle room would be good. So far I only presented my minimal example and not the actual use-case problem I'm trying to solve to not overcomplicate things. Also I tried with a multi-node CRDB cluster in docker, but the improvement was quite small, i.e. very sub-linear.

Answer (score 0):

Performance may also be suffering because of lack of a mounted volume. If it's defaulting to docker's filesystem, that would also negatively impact throughput.

Comment: Using Docker's default filesystem would impact performance, but it looks like both Cockroach and Postgres are being tested in the same conditions. The biggest reason for the performance difference is as per @Radu's answer, multiple ranges on a single node of Cockroach, which isn't a typical workload for Cockroach which is built for multiple nodes receiving work.

Answer (score 0):

As Livius stated above, dropping the indexes is a technique used by many data warehouses, as it helps speed up bulk inserts significantly. I know you say that rows are being "filled continuously", but does that mean from other connections? If not, you can lock the table, drop the indexes, insert the rows, then re-add the indexes afterwards. The problem with retaining the current indexes is that the B-Tree index needs to be handled on each row inserted, and periodically re-balanced.

Additionally, do you really need three separate indexes, each with only one column? Would it be possible to create fewer indexes by adding column(s) to one of the other indexes? In other words, are you typically querying this table using only column `a` in the `WHERE` clause for this table? Is it generally used in conjunction with one of the other columns? Perhaps you tend to query on this table, `JOIN`ed by another table, using `b`, and with `a` in the `WHERE` clause. If that's the case, why not combine the index to be `idx_ab (a, b)`?

Just some thoughts. To be fair, I don't know CockroachDB, but traditional relational databases tend to work similarly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there are multiple connections to the database. Some of them will send `SELECT`s while the others are filling in data. Having the indexed dropped while inserting probably would not be good for the queries (which will approximate about 3000 per second). Also these queries actually will do no joins for now but query sometimes purely with `WHERE a=...`, sometimes with `WHERE b=...` and sometimes with `WHERE c=...`.

Comment: What I've done in the past to help alleviate similar issues was to use replication to handle updates on the primary, and all non-time-sensitive reads hitting the replicated read-only server. This allows you to table-lock the primary table while handling the bulk inserts. This also means that any other writes to the table will be queued up, and run on completion. This is probably overkill for what you're trying to do, but it is another option.

Comment: Side note: if you have any foreign key constraints, and/or triggers, this can also significantly impact INSERT speeds.

Comment: @Chosun CockroachDB does not have table locks nor does it support read-only replicas. It's method of replication is multi-master and on by default whenever there is more than one node in the cluster. (We recommend running in production with at least three nodes, as that's the minimum number of nodes that you need to tolerate one node failure.)

Comment: It's definitely true that foreign key constraints can negatively impact performance in CockroachDB, but it doesn't look like the schema here uses any foreign keys.